# symfony sandbox and virtual host

Tags: symfony1

I have installed symfony sandbox 1.2 and created a virtual host by modifying apache config like this (following this tut http://www.symfony-project.org/askeet/1_0/en/1 but I adapted as sandbox dirs are different from their tuts):

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName askeet
  DocumentRoot "c:/webserver/www/sf_sandbox/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Alias /sf "c:/webserver/www/sf_sandbox/web/images/sf"
  <Directory "c:/webserver/www/sf_sandbox/web">
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from All
  </Directory>
  <Directory "c:/webserver/www/sf_sandbox/web/images/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And modified my hosts file to map askeet to 127.0.0.1

It works fine except symfony tells me:

> If you see no image in this page, you
>   may need to configure your web server
>   so that it gains access to the
>   symfony_data/web/sf/ directory.

Indeed I can't see any images which are stored in c:/webserver/sf_sandbox/web/images/sf as for my symfony sandbox, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hosts file should be

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName askeet
  DocumentRoot "c:/webserver/www/sf_sandbox/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Alias /sf "c:/webserver/www/sf_sandbox/web/sf"
  <Directory "c:/webserver/www/sf_sandbox/web">
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from All
  </Directory>
  <Directory "c:/webserver/www/sf_sandbox/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

because the sf directory is in web/ directory and not in web/images directory?

Comment: sf is a symfony file and it is indeed in web/images.